# How to get multiple blocks timestamps with a single JSON RPC call?

Tags: json-rpc, blocks, timestamp

Is there a way to get data similar to the ones provided by `web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber)` but with multiple blocks at once?

The goal is to get the timestamps for 100 blocks in a row without performing 100 http calls to Infura. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the wiki with all possible calls https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

There are two ways get block:

- eth_getBlockByHash
- eth_getBlockByNumber

But no way to get multiple blocks. You need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have [batch requests](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests) if the client you are using support them.

```
var batch = web3.createBatch();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest', callback));
batch.add(web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).balance.request(address, callback2));
batch.execute();
```

From the documentation:

> Batch reqests are not faster! In fact making many requests at once will in some cases be faster, as requests are processed asynchronously. Batch requests are mainly useful to ensure the serial processing of requests.